# Who is responsible for performing the query EC2 or RDS?

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, query

Normally I run my own MySQL server (within EC2), but I was looking for the possibility's of RDS ( https://aws.amazon.com/rds/ ).

As I understand RDS is (directly after setup) optimized for relational databases. What I don't understand is who is performing the query in the end? Is RDS just an optimized HDD (or SSD ) with MySQL running or does it perform the queries too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RDS is just an EC2 instance with MySQL installed. The only major difference is that AWS installs/manages the software and handles stuff like backups, instead of you.

Comment: Ok, so in the end RDS will perform the MySQL queries and will immediately gives the base EC2 instance some "air" to spare for other things?

Comment: @user3892683 Yes, but it isn't a magic bullet. Depends where the bottleneck - blindly adding an RDS to the mix *can* cause *slower* performance if you're not diagnosing first.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon RDS is not just storage.  It is a special instance type running the DB software, preinstalled on this special instance type.  You connect to it via the Amazon Internal network.

So instead of connecting to localhost:3306 you would connect to the address you get in the console for your RDS instance.

Python:

```
import MySQLdb
db = MySQLdb.connect(
    host = "rds-instance.availability-zone.rds.amazonaws.com",
    user="YourUser",
    passwd="YourPassword", 
    port=1433,
    db="YourDBname")
```